# Counting natural numbers in elixir

Tags: elixir

I an going through the Elixir in Action book and I'm kind of stumped how the following example works.

```
defmodule NaturalNums do
  def print(1), do: IO.puts(1)

  def print(n) do
    print(n - 1)
    IO.puts(n)
  end
end
```

Gives this output:

```
iex(2)> NaturalNums.print(3)
1
2
3
```

What I am confused about is how this module counts upwards from 1 instead of downwards from 3.  Shouldn't 3 be printed first followed by 2 and then 1?  1 being last because it stops the recursion.

A walk through the control flow of this module would be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `puts` call occurs after the recursive call to `print`. So while the inputs passed do follow the order 3,2,1, the `puts` command will get executed in the reverse order. Roughly, this is how it goes:

1. print(3) - original input
2. print(2) - recursive call print(n-1)
3. print(1) - recursive call print(n-1); base case reached
4. puts(1)
5. puts(2) - completes the print(2) call
6. puts(3) - completes the print(3) call

Comment: thanks for this.  but once the base case is reached - how does the function continue and then continue counting upwards?

Answer (score 1):

What matters, is the order of putting a value and doing a recursive call. If the function was

```
def print(n) do
  IO.puts(n)
  print(n - 1)
end
```

(note the changed order compared against your version,) you were getting 3⇒2⇒1 output, because `IO.puts` were to happen *before* recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is really hard to visualise recursion and understand what's going on. You may do some debugging and take some time to analyse the result:

```rb
 defmodule NaturalNums do
  def print(1)  do
    IO.puts "Last step (n=1)"  # <-- debugging
    IO.puts(1)
  end

  def print(n) do
    IO.puts "Starting recursive call (n=#{n})" # <-- debugging
    print(n - 1)
    IO.puts "After recursive call (n=#{n})"    # <-- debugging
    IO.puts(n)
  end
end

NaturalNums.print(5)
```

Here is an output:

```
Starting recursive call (n=5)
Starting recursive call (n=4)
Starting recursive call (n=3)
Starting recursive call (n=2)
Last step (n=1)
1
After recursive call (n=2)
2
After recursive call (n=3)
3
After recursive call (n=4)
4
After recursive call (n=5)
5
```

As you can see, first it does 4 recursive calls, reaches the last step and only then start to print the results in reversed order.

Comment: thanks for this thorough answer.  my question is how does this happen `then start to print the results in reversed order.`? i don't see any mechanism that would store the results or continue the loop after the base case is reached

Answer (score -2):

Check this proposal:

```
numeros = Enum.map(1..10, fn x -> x end)
Enum.map(numeros, fn num -> IO.puts "#{num}" end)
```